# Не отображается код в браузере

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Не отображается код в браузере

```
@using Shop.Data.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Car>
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Главная страница";
}
@{
Layout = "_Layout";
}

<form method="post" asp-controller="Cars"></form>
<h1>Все автомобили</h1>

<br />
    @foreach(var car in Model)
    {
            <div>
                <h2>Модель:@car.Name</h2>
                <p>Цена: @car.Price.ToString("c")</p>
            </div>
    }
<br />
```

Выдает код текстом в самом браузере
Вот контроллер

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Shop.Data.Interfaces;
using Shop.ViewModels;

namespace Shop.Controllers
{
public class CarsController: Controller
{
    private readonly IAllCars _allCars;
    private readonly ICarsCategory _allCategories;

    public CarsController(IAllCars iAllCars, ICarsCategory iCarsCat)
    {
        _allCars= iAllCars;
        _allCategories= iCarsCat;
    }

    [Route("List")]

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Страница с автомобилями";
        CarsListViewModel obj = new()
        {
            allCars = _allCars.Cars,
            currCategory = "Автомобили"
        };
        return View(obj); 
    }
  }
}
```

Возможно проблема в самом program.cs

```
using Shop.Data.Interfaces;
using Shop.Data.Mockc;


namespace Shop
{

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            await context.Response.SendFileAsync("Views/Cars/List.cshtml");
        });
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for 
production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ConfigureServices(services);
            services.AddTransient<IAllCars, MockCars>();
            services.AddTransient<ICarsCategory, MockCategory>();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        }
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name:"default",
            pattern: "{controller=Cars}/{action=List}/{id?}");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapRazorPages();

        app.Run();
    }
  }
}
```

Ошибок никаких нет при этом

Comment: Вьюха принимает `@model IEnumerable<Car>`. А передаётся в неё `CarsListViewModel` - совсем другой тип.

Comment: Возможно, вместо `@foreach(var car in Model)` нужно `@foreach(var car in Model.allCars)`